# Is there a way to mix ng-class using conditional expression with ng-class using string syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to apply a class depending on the index of an ngRepeat, so in that ngRepeat i also have `ng-init="myIndex = $index"`.
In this case I can use `ng-class='"color-" + myIndex'` to apply classes color-0, color-1, color-2, etc.

Also, a different class should be applied if the element is selected, so I'm going with:

`ng-class="{'selected': element.selected}"`

Both ngClass work fine separately, but i cannot find a way to use both of them in the same ngClass.

I tried something like `ng-class="'color-' + myIndex, {'selected': element.selected}"` in many different ways, but always getting the same error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token
>   at column 19 of the expression ['color-' + myIndex, {'selected':
>   element.selected}] starting at [, {'selected': element.selected}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using list notation:**

```
ng-class="['color-' + myIndex, element.selected ? 'selected' : '']"
```

or:

```
ng-class="['color-' + myIndex, {true: 'selected'}[element.selected]]"
```

**Using object notation:**

```
ng-class="{selected: element.selected, {{ 'color-' + myIndex }}: true}"
```

or:

```
ng-class="{selected: element.selected}" class="{{ 'color-' + myIndex }}"
```

Note: this very last method is not recommended as it prevents AngularJS classes (e.g. ng-scope..) from being added.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AngularJS >= v1.4 you can also use this solution:
`ng-class="['color-' + myIndex, {'selected': element.selected}]"`

Comment: That doesn't work. I just tested it, this is the result `class="ng-scope color-4 [object Object]"`.

Comment: Maybe you miss something. Here the working plunkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/ZeUX0B1M79la6QL2tr5i/

Comment: Interesting, your method did give the output I mentioned in my previous comment when I tested it with AngularJS `v1.2.2`. But when I tested it with the latest version `v1.6.8`, it worked fine. I owe you an apology ;)

Comment: You're right. My solution works fine with AngularJS >= v1.4